# What does "C1-4 NON END" mean on a Qatar Airways flight ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, terminology, qatar-airways

[Example](https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/library/ssp/document.php?code=spa-cmr-2018-11-08/dac1191de858a7739e246e6e1a31a20f-e9c89bde-9052-42e7-a1c4-225cf41df17d&mime=application/pdf&save=%20%7E%20avia%202940.72.pdf) ([mirror](https://archive.ph/kqUCn), [mirror 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20210604184205/https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/library/ssp/document.php?code=spa-cmr-2018-11-08%2Fdac1191de858a7739e246e6e1a31a20f-e9c89bde-9052-42e7-a1c4-225cf41df17d&mime=application%2Fpdf&save=%2520%7E%2520avia%25202940.72.pdf)):

[image]

What does "C1-4 NON END" mean on a Qatar Airways flight ticket?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- C1-4 : for flight coupons 1 through 4, inclusive
- NON END : the coupon is non-endorsable, i.e. you cannot apply it toward travel on another carrier, so if another airline accepts it, Qatar will not pay them for it
- CHNG PENALTIES AS PER RULE : change penalties apply according to the rules of the fare

These are common restrictions on discount economy fares.

Comment: Thanks what does "for flight coupons 1 through 4" mean?

Comment: It's a term that dates back to paper tickets, referring to a discrete part of the ticket for which passage was valid for the passenger. For a simple case, if you're flying AAA-BBB-CCC and then CCC-BBB-AAA, you might expect to have four coupons: AAA-BBB, BBB-CCC, BBB-CCC, and BBB-AAA. A coupon doesn't necessary correspond to a segment, however.

Comment: Thanks!  [In what case doesn't a coupon correspond to a segment?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/166176/1810)