# What are the definitions of stages and sequences when describing a flight, and how do they compare against leg/portion/sector/segment?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, terminology

I read:

> - Question: [In what case doesn't a coupon correspond to a segment?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/166176/1810)
> - Comment: This is getting into the weeds of terminology that most travelers don't need to deal with; there are also *sectors* and *legs* and *portions* and *stages* and *sequences* and more, just different ways of dividing up the trip and dividing up the money. – [choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster) [Jun 9 at 2:41](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166176/in-what-case-doesnt-a-coupon-correspond-to-a-segment/166245#comment413623_166176) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210613163654/https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166176/in-what-case-doesnt-a-coupon-correspond-to-a-segment/166245#comment413623_166176))

I couldn't find the definitions of stages and sequences. What are the definitions of stages and sequences and how do they compare against leg/portion/sector/segment?

---

Here are the [IATA definitions](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506153744/https://www.iata.org/contentassets/04c5400c2dcd4b05a520330672b13ef6/iata-passenger-glossary-of-terms.xlsx) I could find on dividing up the trip and dividing up the money:

| Term Name | Description | Source of Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Coupon | The portion of the Passenger Ticket and Baggage Check or Excess Baggage Ticket that indicates particular places between which the coupon is good for carriage. |  |
| Leg | The space between two consecutive scheduled stops on any given flight. | IATA,PSCRMe34,CHPT 1,RESO 766 |
| Leg | The operation between a departure station and the next arrival station. | IATA,SSIMe38 (2011),CHPT 1.1,RP 1761b |
| Portion | One segment or consecutive segments (even though gap intervenes) via any one Member. | IATA,Reso766 |
| Sector | (see "Leg") | IATA,SSIM,RP1761b |
| Segment | A leg or a group of legs from boarding point of a passenger to a deplaning point on a given flight. | IATA,PSCRMe34,CHPT 1,RESO 766 |
| Segment | (Sometimes referred to as City Pair) The operation between board point and any subsequent off point within the same flight. | IATA,SSIMe38 (2011),CHPT 1.1,RP 1761b |

Comment: I feel that this series of questions goes beyond the scope of Travel Stack Exchange. Not using the closing hammer but I did vote down.

Comment: @Willeke thanks for the comment, I think this is important for travelers to properly understand the terminology around tickets / flights (e.g., to understand the rules that applies to a ticket, such as "PAX /C1-4 NON END/CHNG PENALTIES AS PER RULE", or when discussing with airlines' employees).

Comment: it's really not. If you're having an argument with customer support about change fees, demonstrating your knowledge of what a stage is will not change anything

Comment: @KateGregory I think  it doesn't hurt to learn the meaning of words. Maybe that's why we have a tag for it? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology

Comment: This question makes my head ache just looking at it, never mind trying to read it. I cannot imagine any circumstances in which it would be useful to know the answer.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the airline you're corresponding with uses these terms internally as defined by IATA (and even if they do, individual staff members might not know them to this level of detail).

Comment: @GrayTaylor of course, there's no guarantee in life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.lot.com/cy/en/conditions-of-carriage ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210711160809/https://www.lot.com/cy/en/conditions-of-carriage)), the term "sequence" designates the order of the flight coupons:

> The carrier’s fares require that the passenger should travel the respective journey segments in the **sequence** in which they are reflected in the ticket. If the passenger intends to travel disregarding the original **sequence** of journey segments, he/she should change his/her ticket in accordance with his/her actual journey intention.

The document on the [Main terms used in civil aviation statistics by the ICAO](https://www.icao.int/dataplus_archive/Documents/GLOSSARY.docx) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210711161150/https://www.icao.int/dataplus_archive/Documents/GLOSSARY.docx)) defines a flight stage as follows:

> Flight stage. A flight stage is the operation of an aircraft from take-off to its next landing. A flight stage is classified as either international or domestic based on the following definitions: [...].