# How is the part of a route between two consecutive waypoints called?

Tags: air-travel, road-trips, terminology

What is the name of the part of a route/path/flight between two consecutive waypoints?

Do "Route leg" or just "Leg" appropriate terms?

Comment: **section** could also be used: [road section](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/road-section): ***road section** means a part of the public road which is continuous in terms of transportation, and the beginning and end of which are delimited by kilometer markers*;

Comment: The idiomatic term to use is **leg**. Please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/leg): ***3** A section or stage of a journey or process.*

Comment: Are you asking about aviation terminology?  If so, [Aviation.SE] is the better venue for your question.

Comment: @phoog the last time I did that on a similar terminology question, I got close voted, down voted and was told to post on Travel SE. 
The question was eventually removed: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/87689/1400

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I don't have sufficient reputation to see that question.  What was the term?  Passenger matters are off topic there (including IATA concepts such as "leg" and "segment"), but questions relating to air navigation waypoints, which are generally off topic here (a waypoint is not an airport, notably), are on topic there.

Comment: @phoog https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnpRe.png The question was "What are the definitions of stages and sequences when describing a flight, and how do they compare against leg/portion/sector/segment?" It didn't receive an outstanding welcome on Travel  SE either: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/166280/1810

Comment: @phoog I get your point. Makes sense.  But I think SE is too fragmented. Eg the OP question could also be asked on one of the two SE websites for learning English.

Answer (score 2):

The path which can be travelled between two waypoints (without reference to any specific flight) is an airway or air route or flight path.

When part of the [flight plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_plan) for a specific flight, it’s a segment or route segment.

Note that segment has different semantics at the flight plan level compared to the use in fare rules and the like.

Answer (score -1):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waypoint calls it a leg or a stage:

> [A waypoint] most often refers to coordinates which specify one's position on the globe at the end of each "leg" (stage) of an air flight or sea passage.