# What does “PAX” mean on a Qatar Airways flight ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, terminology, qatar-airways

[Example](https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/library/ssp/document.php?code=spa-cmr-2018-11-08/dac1191de858a7739e246e6e1a31a20f-e9c89bde-9052-42e7-a1c4-225cf41df17d&mime=application/pdf&save=%20%7E%20avia%202940.72.pdf) ([mirror](https://archive.ph/kqUCn), [mirror 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20210604184205/https://tenders.procurement.gov.ge/public/library/ssp/document.php?code=spa-cmr-2018-11-08%2Fdac1191de858a7739e246e6e1a31a20f-e9c89bde-9052-42e7-a1c4-225cf41df17d&mime=application%2Fpdf&save=%2520%7E%2520avia%25202940.72.pdf)):

[image]

What does "PAX" mean on a Qatar Airways flight ticket?

Typically, PAX=passenger, but in that case I don't understand why the ticket says "passenger" there.

Comment: My guess is that the data shown is parsed from standardised rules included in the ticket or the fare rules and the parsing went wrong. Or the original formatting of that text.

Comment: FYI You show an image as supporting information about your question about Qatar airlines.  That is sufficient.  But then you add in a link to a PDF hosted on a government site in the country of Georgia, and to a random link shortener.  Those links are totally unnecessary and potentially problematic and IMHO should be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "C1-4 NON END" mean on a Qatar Airways flight ticket?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166097/what-does-c1-4-non-end-mean-on-a-qatar-airways-flight-ticket)

Comment: @GregHewgill no, that question doesn't address PAX

Comment: @PeterM it's best practice to mention the sources of images. Also someone may wish to view the entire flight ticket to try to understand.

Comment: Wait, that's not even your own ticket? You just found a ticket image somewhere on the internet and are asking multiple questions about the exact notations that happen to be printed on the ticket? You can't possibly have knowledge of the exact terms under which that ticket was purchased. I don't think this sort of hypothetical question is suitable here.

Comment: @GregHewgill I had the same mention on my last QR ticket. We can now focus on the question?

Comment: I read the line as saying Passenger Ticket, Coupons 1-4, Non-endorsable, Change Penalties Apply as per Rule. /shrug What penalties did you have to pay when you did not use your ticket and didn't cancel it within the time-frame allowed? Oh... you didn't do this, it isn't a problem you are trying to solve. hmmmm

Comment: @CGCampbell What's the point of saying Passenger Ticket on a flight ticket? Are there non-passenger tickets?

Comment: It's not restating that it is a passenger ticket. It's saying the ticket goes by the rules of change penalties as apply to a passenger ticket with 4 coupons. Why is this so hard to understand and what does it matter?

Comment: *OR* it is stating that the passenger ticket, including the parts 1-4, all have that rule applied.

Comment: @CGCampbell are you asking why understanding the content of a flight ticket matters? You're making a good point. Anyway, too bad you edited the ellipses out of your previous comment..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer: PAX=passenger, and the ticket says "passenger" there because the entire line "PAX /C1-4 NON END/CHNG PENALTIES AS PER RULE" was copied from the  Amadeus program (which mentions `PAX`).

---

Looking at the [Amadeus training manual (Jan. 2012)](https://issuu.com/amqa/docs/amadeus_training_manual_jan_2012), the PAX line comes from [Amadeus](https://amadeus.com/en):

[image]

and PAX [means](http://www.amadeus.com/web/binaries/blobs/140/802/AMADEUS%20TRAINING%20MANUAL%20190.pdf) passenger:

[image]

Additionally, [Locutus_WPC](https://www.reddit.com/user/Locutus_WPC) mentioned on [Reddit](https://redd.it/nxjt6t):

> In this context PAX probably refers to an adult passenger. Would’ve said CHD or INF if describing a child or infant fare.

Comment: This feels very muchas 'not an answer'.

Comment: @Willeke it does confirm that PAX = passenger, therefore it is an answer. Expansions are welcome though.

Comment: @Aganju please note that it is absolutely fine and allowed to answer one's own questions on SE.

Comment: @JoErNanO : I know, and I support it. The focus in my comment is on ‘Frank’, ‘ton of’ and ‘theoretical’.